# How to enlarge the added vector asset in android which is too small in bottomNavingationView(footer)

Tags: android, android-studio, android-vectordrawable

One of my footer icons shows very small and if I try to enlarge by increasing the width and height in drawable XML it shrinks and shows very small.

How can I make the SVG as large icon in android.

Answer (score 0):

Make a new asset from the existing svg with higher dp.

Comment: But the icon is a new one which I have inserted. I not needed an existing one, i need my new icon in my app

Comment: Yes, take your new icon and add it again as an asset, just with higher dp: `Ressource Manager > '+' > Local file (SVG, PSD)` and resize the dp to your preference.

Comment: Tried still the icon is in its exact size